# Labels not appearing on sent emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I label all emails when I send them and over the past couple days, I'm noticing that when I check my sent mail folder, many of the emails I've labeled have somehow lost that label. I can manually label them again in the sent mail folder but this is a time-suck I would rather avoid.

Any ideas on what may be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any third-party apps/services that have access to your Gmail account? If not, all I can think is that it's a bug in Gmail.

Comment: No, there's no other apps or service.